# How do I position a GridLayout off-screen using NativeScript/CSS?

Tags: angular2-nativescript

How do I set the starting position of a GridLayout off-screen?  When I click on it, I will trigger a keyframe that will bring into view.  Here is what I am trying but it does not work.

This is the html

```
<GridLayout  columns="*" rows="auto,*" class="test-control" ">
     <Label class="h12 page-text" text="TEST"  row="0 ">
            </Label>
    <Label class="h1 page-text " text="TEST"  row="1 ">
            </Label>
```

This is the css:

```
      .test-control {
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    background-color: #0E5240;
    color: #FF0000;
    height: auto;
    bottom: -100%;
    overflow: hidden;
   }
```

I have the keyframs and animation working. I just need to start the GridLayout off-screen.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote an article on this. Check it out and see if it helps: https://medium.com/@scottmgerstl/slide-a-view-in-from-off-screen-nativescript-angular-8e305f50217a

Here's the accompanying code:

snackbar.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { screen, ScreenMetrics } from 'platform';
const screenScale: number = screen.mainScreen.scale;
const offScreenMargin: number = screen.mainScreen.heightDIPs * -1;
@Directive({
    selector: '[snackbar]'
})
export class SnackbarDirective {
    // Let an implementor know when the view has left the screen
    @Output() private dismissed: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>(false);
    private element: ElementRef;
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        this.element = el;
        this.element.nativeElement.marginBottom = offScreenMargin;
    }
    public show(): void {
            this.element.nativeElement.animate({
            translate: { x: 0, y: this.getTranslateYHeight() * -1 },
            duration: 750
        });
    }
    public dismiss(): void {
        this.element.nativeElement.animate({
            translate: { x: 0, y: this.getTranslateYHeight() },
            duration: 750
        })
        .then(() => this.dismissed.emit(true));
    }
    private getTranslateYHeight(): number {
        return this.element.nativeElement.getMeasuredHeight() / screenScale;
    }
}
```

implementor.component.html

```
<GridLayout columns="auto,auto" rows="auto,auto">
    <!-- My Component Page Markup -->
    <Button (tap)="onOpenButtonTap($event)" 
            text="Open" row="0" col="0"></Button>
    <Button (tap)="onCloseButtonTap($event)" 
            text="Close" row="0" col="1"></Button>
    <StackLayout snackbar class="slide" col="0" colSpan="2" row="1">
    </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

implementor.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { SnackbarDirective } from './snackbar.directive';
@Component(...)
export class ImplementorComponent {
    @ViewChild(SnackbarDirective) private snack: SnackbarDirective;
    private onOpenButtonTap(): void {
        this.snack.show();
    }
    private onCloseButtonTap(): void {
        this.snack.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Here’s whats going on:

using the bracket notation in the directive selector[snackbar] you are able to attach a directive (including components) to elements instead of nesting them inside of other views (explained in the blog post mentioned above). In order to gain access to the directive’s methods, you reference it in the implementing component by type using the ViewChild decorator from angular core@ViewChild(SnackbarComponent). Be aware that if you want to add multiple directives to the view of the same type you will need to use the @ViewChildren() decorator instead and iterate through to find the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

To position a view off screen you can use the `translateX` and/or `translateY` properties. I use it in many apps for custom side menus, bottom sheets, forms, etc. Works great.

Comment: [Brad , but it seems that off-screen layout is not "kept" ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48701445/nativescript-stacklayout-does-not-layout-properly)